# how to show dialogs when running powershell script

Tags: shell, powershell

I want to start the "npm init" process and display the dialog with info about the package.
But when I run my powershell script it seems like it starts the command, but I can't see the dialog.

Do I need to add some logic for pausing the script until the dialog is finished?

script.ps1:

```
Write-Host "Initiating LC Project/ASP.NET Core";
npm init;
```

Comment: What dialog are you talking about?

Comment: omit the `--force`

Comment: yes my bad. it's not there anymore

Comment: @Bill_Stewart when you run npm init you get a series of questions to answer. it's this dialog I want to display

Comment: @TheRuler: Without `--force`, the interactive prompts should appear (and do in my tests) - are you saying you still don't see them? If so, please provide more information about your environment. If your problem was solved by removing `--force`, please consider deleting your question, as it is unlikely to benefit future readers.

Comment: @mklement0 no removing trust didn't do it. can you share your code?

Comment: @TheRuler: (By _trust_ I assume you meant `--force`). If I put the code from your question as-is into a `*.ps1` script and run that with npm version 6.10.0 in Windows PowerShell 5.1.17763.592 on Windows 10, I do get the prompts.